# How to send Some Value in Button to Textbox in c sharp?

Tags: c#

[image]

I was tired to try it ,,
who became my problem is , I possessed the key , the first key and the plus 1 button again less how when the plus button is clicked then appears the number 1 in the textbox and if the press will again increase as well with less buttons .
this my code :

```
private void BtnTmbhCola_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Convert.ToInt32(txtCola.Text + 1);
   txtdvr8chanel.Text = Val(txtdvr8chanel.Text) + 1;
   txttotaldvr.Text = Format(Val(txttotaldvr.Text), "Rp,#,###,###,0.000.000") + 530000;

   If (txtdvr8chanel.Text = 1 )
        {
            btntmbh8ch.Enabled = True;
        }
}
```

i got eror

Comment: You are looking for the code for that or, what is your problem?

Comment: Your question is difficult to decipher. It may help to show your code. Presumably you've got a backing int that holds the quantity. When it is zero you display a blank value in the  text box. When the plus button is clicked that integer is incremented and the textbox is updated to show this new value. Have you attached an event handler to the buttons? Can you step through the code and see if it is being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just add simple code to your buttons, Concern about validations and things.

```
    private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            int count = 0;
            textBox2.Text = count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            int count = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
            ++count;
            textBox2.Text = count.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void minusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "0" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            int count = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
            --count;
            textBox2.Text = count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is very helpful thanks ..
Now I am happy ..
to #codelahiru

Comment: Happy to hear. But always try to think how you can archive some goals. can you please mark it as answer then.

Comment: I do not know how, ?

Comment: follow the steps in link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version I can imagine would be this one:

.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" Text="Old Text"/>
    <Button Content="Sender" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

.xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeTextBox.Text = "NewText";
}
```

Seeing that you are building a shop you may want to dive a bit deeper into WPF.

Consider making you Product a Model in the MVVM sense of the word and create a View to display it and connect them using a viewmodel.

Make a CartItem as a Model,... make a cart as a model,...

Here is a more complex example that points you into that direction.
.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="+" Command="{Binding ProductInc}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cola}"  />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cola.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Content="-" Command="{Binding ProductDec}" CommandParameter="{Binding Cola}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

.xaml.cs

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int count = 0;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set
        {
            if (value == count) return;
            count = value;
            if (null == PropertyChanged) return;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        }
    }
}

class SimpleCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }
    private Action<T> execute;
    public SimpleCommand(Action<T> execute) { this.execute = execute; }
    public void Execute(object parameter) { execute((T)parameter); }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Product Cola { get; set; }
    public ICommand ProductInc { get { return new SimpleCommand<Product>(OnProductInc); } }
    public ICommand ProductDec { get { return new SimpleCommand<Product>(OnProductDec); } }
    private void OnProductInc(Product product) { ++product.Count; }
    private void OnProductDec(Product product) { --product.Count; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Cola = new Product { Count = 0 };
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: #Johannes This is very helpful even though I do not quite understand the xml ..
Thank you already want to answer